# How to group dates together in an array, removing any overlapping dates

Tags: php, date

I have an array which holds start and end dates like the following:

```
$dates[] = array('start'=> '2015-01-01', 'end'=> '2016-05-01');
$dates[] = array('start'=> '2016-01-01', 'end'=> '2016-09-11');
$dates[] = array('start'=> '2017-01-05', 'end'=> '2018-02-01');
$dates[] = array('start'=> '2017-01-01', 'end'=> '2017-05-05');
```

I want to merge the dates together and remove overlapping dates to produce a new array of dates without any overlap. The result of the above would be:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2015-01-01
        [end] => 2016-09-11
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2017-01-01
        [end] => 2018-02-01
    )
```

I'm rather stuck on this. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: Two questions: 1. Is the array sorted by start? 2. Is it possible that an end date with a lower start date will have a higher end date? For example:  `[2015-01-01, 2017-05-05] and [2016-01-01 2016-09-11]`

Comment: In the example in my post it's not sorted by start, but I can sort it by start not a problem. re: your second question, yes that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the late hour of the night it will probably not be the most elegant code, but you will get the idea:

First you want to sort the array by `start` date:

```
usort($dates, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a["start"]) - strtotime($b["start"]);
});
```

Then you want to initialize the result array, and two more variables to hold the last `$start` and `$end` times.

Now you iterate the array and only push a new row if the current start date is bigger than the last end date. If so, you also set the last `$start` date to the current one. The last `$end` date you always set to the biggest (compare between current and last).

After the iteration you want to add the last row which your `$start` and `$end` variables are holding.

```
$result = [];
$start = null;
$end = null;

function addToResult(&$result, &$start, &$end, &$date = null)
{
    if (!$date || !$start || strtotime($date["start"]) > strtotime($end)) {
        if ($start && $end) {
            $result[] = ["start" => $start, "end" => $end];
        }

        if ($date) {
            $start = $date["start"];
            $end = $date["end"];
        }
    }

    $end = $date && strtotime($end) < strtotime($date["end"]) ? $date["end"] : $end;
}

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    addToResult($result, $start, $end, $date);
}

addToResult($result, $start, $end);
```

https://3v4l.org/Ej40b